# How to get on python current time?

Tags: python, date, time

I need to have the date.
The format of the time should be `2017-01-18T07:34:35Z`
I have tried this but it does not work:

```
import datetime
i = datetime.datetime.now()
date = %i.year "-" %i.month "-" %i.day "T" %i.hour ":" %i.minute ":" %i.second "Z"
```

Comment: Please read the docs of `datetime`, especially the part about `strftime`.

Comment: It is actually really easy to get a time formatted how you want. There are countless examples on the net. I would just google (python date time) and see all the very useful examples many of them will also lead back to Q/A here on StackOverflow. please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", gmtime())

# Will output
'Thu, 03 May 2017 16:21:01'
```

for your example use:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%SZ", gmtime())
2017-03-05T07:34:35Z
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    import time

    now = time.strftime("%c")
```

see more in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-get-current-date-time-in-python/

Comment: Nice didn't know about strftime(%c), but OP wanted a conversion with a 'T' before time and 'Z' afterwards

Comment: "T"  + time.strftime("%x") and  time.strftime("%X") + "Z"